# ReferenceError: message is not defined - Welcome Message - embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I was playing with my welcome message and wanted to make it an embed, I ended up re-writing it all to work with the embed, however after I finished, I got the error `message is not defined`.

```
var welcomePath = './Storage/welcome.json';
var welcomeRead = fs.readFileSync(welcomePath);
var welcomeFile = JSON.parse(welcomeRead);

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  var serverId = member.guild.id;
  if (!welcomeFile[serverId]) {
    console.log('Welcome is disabled!');
  } else {
    let welcomeChannel = welcomeFile[serverId].channel,
    let setChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === welcomeChannel);
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("Test")
      .setAuthor("Test")
      .setColor(3447003)
      .setDescription("Test")
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL);
    member.guild.channels.get(setChannel).send({
      embed
    });
  }
});
```

The error pertains to this line

```
let setChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === welcomeChannel);
```

I do really want to learn JS, and keep finding myself hitting this brick walls where I need to simply ask for help. I am also unsure if you fix my `message is not defined` that my code will actually do anything.

Comment: Where did you define message ?
You must define message variable to use it, otherwise is undefined.

Comment: I know what `message is not defined` means, my issue was I was unsure on how to define it. Anyway, the question was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message is not defined, you should look for member.

let setChannel = **member**.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === welcomeChannel);

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    var serverId = member.guild.id;
    if (!welcomeFile[serverId]) {
      console.log('Welcome is disabled!')
    } else {
      let welcomeChannel = welcomeFile[serverId].channel
      let setChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === welcomeChannel);
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("Test")
        .setAuthor("Test")
        .setColor(3447003)
        .setDescription("Test")
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
        member.guild.channels.get(setChannel).send({embed});
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it might have been a simple fix but could not see it! Do you know why the line `.setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)` is saying message is not defined? Or should I create a new post?

Comment: 'message' is still not defined there.